# The background of my transparent logo turns white when I export my InDesign to PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I use the latest version of InDesign, and when I export to PDF (to print) it turns the logo's background from transparent to white.

How do I stop this behavior?

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: What's the nature of the logo? Placed raster? Paced vector? Drawn in InDesign?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the overprint preview is enabled in the pdf player (try "always") :

- edit > preferences > page display > overprint preview